# "in every corner" or "on every corner"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Media are taking our lives. Nowadays there is a screen turned on **in/on every corner**.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-at-every-corner) says it is on/at every corner. But there are a lot of "in every corner" on the Internet, even more than "on every corner". Are those (in/on/at) all equally correct?

As is clear from the sentence I provided, I want to talk generally, both indoors and outdoors.

Comment: Can you please give more context. What web are you talking about? What do you mean by "screen turned"? If you mean "street corner" there is no "in" because the corners are external corners.

Comment: There are certain cities where there is a hooker on every corner, and certain rooms where there is a hooker in every corner.

Comment: The question in the title is different from the one highlighted. The sentence *Nowadays there is a screen turned **on** in every corner.* uses *on* meaning that the screen is working, it is alight.

Comment: @WeatherVane Edited.

Comment: @mama - I would interpret that sentence to be speaking of a bar where there are TV screens wherever you look.

Comment: @HotLicks More context added. I am talking generally.

Comment: @mama More context added. I am talking generally

Comment: @WeatherVane More context added. I am talking generally.

Comment: Screens are usually indoors, "in the corner" of a room. If they were outdoors they might be "on the corner" or "at the corner" of the street. See the comment from Hot Licks.

Comment: @WeatherVane What if we want to say generally. If we are talking about the media domination, we mean every corner both indoors and outdoors, both small screens in  side houses/bars/etc and big screens on every corner of the street.

Comment: @HotLicks What if we want to say generally. If we are talking about the media domination, we mean every corner both indoors and outdoors, both small screens in side houses/bars/etc and big screens on every corner of the street.

Comment: Perhaps "corner" is the wrong metaphor - that is more appropriate to televisions, but the WWW isn't on TV: The media that is "taking our lives" is now on people's phones, in their hands.

Comment: If you want to say it generally you should probably find a different idiom.

Comment: I would suggest that it depends on whether most of the corners under discussion are internal or external, regardless of whether they are indoors or outdoors. For instance if you were talking about a sports stadium (where the corners are internal) you might say there was a screen _in_ every corner but if you were in a club with a free-standing, octagonal, bar it might have a screen _on_ every corner.

Comment: Close-voters please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you’re having is that both “in” and “on” could work, but neither is *quite* right. Are you dead-set on this idiom? If not, you might try:

> “...a screen turned on everywhere you look.”
>
> “...a screen turned on in every direction.”

But if you *must* use this idiom for some reason, I would suggest some variant of:

> “...a screen [turned on] in and on every corner.”

Essentially using both idioms. To get around packing all those prepositions into one spot (i.e. “...on in and on...), maybe try:

> “...an attention-sucking screen in and on every corner.”

Answer (score 0):

The Cambridge definition makes it clear that it refers to street corners, therefore out of doors. If you want to suggest the corners of a room (indoors), 'in' would be more appropriate.

Comment: as said in comments, I am talking generally, both indoors and outdoors.

Comment: @Sasan - You mean like "in all corners of the world"?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, both indoors and outdoors. In every hands, in every room, every bar, every corner of the street, like everywhere.